# How to enable maintenance mode via console in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i would like to set my Shopware 6 instance to maintenance mode using my update script.
Is there any way to enable the maintenance mode using the bin/console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the maintenance mode for a specific sales channel with

```
bin/console sales-channel:maintenance:enable salesChannelId
```

Or you can enable it for all sales channels with the --all flag

```
bin/console sales-channel:maintenance:enable --all
```

Works the same for disabling.